# SQL slow only when comparing values in a JOIN (Presto / Amazon Athena)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have two tables, one containing data the other is metadata.

The main data table contains a grid of geospatial coordinates (up to billions of rows). The coordinates are projected to a specific coordinate system. The relevant part of the schema is:

```
 ------------------
| x     | smallint |
|------------------|
| y     | smallint |
|------------------|
| value | string   |
 ------------------
```

The metadata table contains the corresponding latitude and longitude values for the x, y coordinates. The relevant part of the schema is:

```
 ----------------------------
| x         | smallint       |
|----------------------------|
| y         | smallint       |
|----------------------------|
| latitude  | decimal(18,15) |
|----------------------------|
| longitude | decimal(18,15) |
 ----------------------------
```

A JOIN on these two tables allows one to know the actual latitude/longitude for a particular X/Y coordinate. This will make queries on the table easier since you don't need to know anything about the map projection.

A sample query that retrieves rows from the table:

```
SELECT 
  main.x,
  main.y,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  value
FROM database.main JOIN database.meta
ON main.x=meta.x AND main.y=meta.y
WHERE
  main.x=1 AND main.y<=2
```

The result set would look like:

```
 --------------------------------------
| x | y | latitude | longitude | value |
|--------------------------------------|
| 1 | 1 | 12.345   | 54.321    | row1  |
|--------------------------------------|
| 1 | 2 | 12.345   | 98.765    | row2  |
 --------------------------------------
```

This query only takes 1-2 seconds, great!

My problem is, when I run a query that adds a WHERE clause comparing latitude and longitudes, the query works but it takes over 60 seconds to run...

For example:

```
SELECT 
  main.x,
  main.y,
  latitude,
  longitude,
  value
FROM database.main JOIN database.meta
ON main.x=meta.x AND main.y=meta.y
WHERE
  latitude=DECIMAL '12.345' AND longitude=DECIMAL '98.765'
```

I know that I am probably missing something fundamental about SQL and JOINs that is causing this query to be slow. Independent queries on either table are ultra fast so I *know* I'm doing something wrong here that has to do with the JOIN.

So the question is, how do I make it so that this (seemingly) simple comparison completes in only a few seconds rather than over 60 seconds?

Comment: Please share the indexing details on your table(s).

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for, there are no indexes. These queries are run against flat files using PrestoDB/Amazon Athena

Comment: Well question was earlier tagged MySQL too. Not sure about PrestoDB though. Check if `DESCRIBE` command works ?

Comment: Yes, that tag was by mistake, sorry. I've included the relevant schema info in the question.

Comment: Side note: Athena apparently [has dedicated geospatial types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/querying-geospatial-data.html).  Otherwise, my guess is that Athena isn't auto-building indices for non-key-column data

Comment: I have noticed the geospatial query support but I'm just not at the point where I understand enough about it yet. Maybe I just need to move toward using that feature instead, I'm just worried that I'll put the work in and the query speed won't be improved.

Comment: It's a bit strange that the join by itself appears fast and you only have the issue on the filter.  Could be that there is an arbitrary limit to the number of rows that return on the query with no filter.  So the query stops or returns results when that limit is hit (IE limit 100).  What's the performance like if you just select from main on your filter?

Comment: @vanlee1987 question is important. The fast query -- is it fast to produce _some_ results or to produce _all_ results? With additional WHERE condition, your query should not be slower in producing _all_ results, but is likely to be slower to produce _some_ (_first_) results.
If this doesn't answer the problem, you should compare EXPLAIN plans (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/explain.html) of the queries.

Comment: @vanlee1987 adding a LIMIT does not change the speed. There are really not that many rows in the result set for a query like this, less than 100 anyway, sometimes less than 10.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen Unfortunately, EXPLAIN statements are not allowed for Athena https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html

Comment: That's tough. Without EXPLAIN, it's just guessing. Why don't you try this on a regular Presto cluster? Either EMR or just Presto (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07DKV5659) will do? Of course, in any case you won't be able to run as old Presto version as Athena does, but you might still get understanding of the underlying problem.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen that is a good idea. I will attempt to get Presto working in EMR - since it seems to be easy to set up - and do some testing

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with geospatial data you need to take advantage of the geo-functionality of sql in order to speed up your queries. 
So firstly create a Point column with:

```
    create table test_geospatial(
    ...,
    ...,
    long decimal,
    lat decimal,
    point as geography::Point(long, lat, SRID) persisted
    )
```

And then create an index on this column:

```
create spatial index SPIX_Geocodes_Point on test_geospatial(point) using geography_auto_grid
```

Answer (score -2):

The most likely explanation for poor performance when adding a `JOIN` is that there is no index that can be used to optimize the join.

In your case, specifying on index on `main(x,y)` is most likely to speed up the `JOIN`.

Comment: I don't think indexes are a thing in Presto since it quickly scans flat files in columnar format. Hence, the metadata table already is the index in this context. Also, when I perform the JOIN without the comparison, it is very quick, would a lack of index explain that problem? Or maybe I could alter the metadata table in such a way that it can perform better?